# Possible error in very large numbers in the Fibonacci sequence (Python 2.7.6 integer math)

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Edited to put questions in bold.**

I wrote the following Python code (using Python 2.7.6) to calculate the Fibonacci sequence. It doesn't use any extra libraries, just the core python modules.

**I was wondering if there was a limit to how may terms of the sequence I could calculate,** perhaps due to the absurd length of the resulting integers, **or if there would be a point where Python no longer performed the calculations accurately.**

Also, **for the fibopt(n) function, it seems to sometimes return the term under the one requested (e. g. 99th instead of 100th) but always works at lower terms (1st, 2nd, 10th, 15th). Why is that?**

```
def fibopt(n): # Returns term "n" of the Fibonacci sequence.
    f = [0,1] # List containing the first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence.
    x = 0 # Empty integer to store the next value in the sequence. Not really necessary.
    optnum = 2 # Number of calculated entries in the sequence. Starts at 2 (0, 1).
    while optnum < n: # Until the "n"th value in the sequence has been calculated.
        if optnum % 10000 == 0:
            print "Calculating index number %s." % optnum # Notify the user for every 10000th value calculated. This is useful because the program can take a very long time to calculate higher values (e. g. about 15 minutes on an i7-4790 for the 10000000th value).
        x = [f[-1] + f[-2]] # Calculate the next value in the sequence based of the previous two. This could be built into the next line.
        f.extend(x) # Append that value to the sequence. This could be f.extend([f[-1] + f[-2]]) instead.
        optnum +=1 # Increment the counter for number of values calculated by 1.
        del f[:-2] # Remove all values from the table except for the last two. Without this, the integers become so long that they fill 16 GB of RAM in seconds.
    return f[:n] # Returns the requested term of the sequence.

def fib(n): # Similar to fibopt(n), but returns all of the terms in the sequence up to and including term "n". Can use a lot of memory very quickly.
    f = [0,1]
    x = 0
    while len(f) < n:
        x = [f[-1] + f[-2]]
        f.extend(x)
    return f[:n]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I should probably clarify that in the post: Will this become inaccurate at a certain point? Why does it return the n-1th term instead of the nth sometimes?

Comment: @LukaSubo, you _must_ do it in the post.

Comment: @ForceBru I've dited the post and the title to better reflect what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is: integer math in Python is easy -- there are no overflows.

As long as your integers can fit within a C `long`, Python will use that. Once you go past that, it will auto-promote to arbitrary-precision integers (which means it'll be slower and use more memory, but the calculations will remain correct).

The only limits are:

1. The amount of memory addressable by the Python process. If you're using 32-bit Python, you need to be able to fit all of your data within 2 gigabytes or RAM (get past that and your program will fail with `MemoryError`). If you're using 64-bit Python, your physical RAM + swapfile is the theoretical limit.
2. The time you're willing to wait while calculations are being performed. The larger your ints, the slower the calculations are. If you ever hit your swap space, your program will reach continental drift levels of slow.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I believe it is 64 bit Python. So it should be able to calculate until the last 3 terms in the sequence fill all of the RAM and SWAP available?

Comment: That's a good approximation, yeah (but remember that Python objects are larger than they seem, that the runtime has overhead and that memory fragmentation is a thing).

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Capabilities notwithstanding, though, the number produced should remain accurate, no?

Comment: Yes, integers don't lose precision. If you get inaccurate numbers, it means there's a bug in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Python integers can express arbitrary-length values and will not be automatically converted to float. You can check by simply creating a very large number and checking its type:

```
>>> type(2**(2**25))
<class 'int'>  # long in Python 2.x
```

fibopt returns `f[:n]`, and that is a list. You seem to expect it to return a term, so either the expectation (the first comment) or the implementation must change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Concerning f[:n]: oops, that's layover from the fib(n) function. I meant to change that to f[-1], which should instead yield only the last item stored in the list (in this case an integer). Would that work correctly?

Comment: The OP seems to be using Python 2 (as indicated by the print statement), so the type would be `long`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Correct, Python 2.7.6 on Linux Mint 17.2 (Kernel 3.13.0-37). Which, come to think of it, is a > 2 year old kernel... I should probably update to 4.4...

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Python 2.7 documentation, there is a section on Fibonacci numbers. In this section on Fibonacci numbers, the arbitrary end is not the elongated answer we would all want to view. It shortens it.

If this does not answer your question, please see: 4.6 Defining Functions.

If you have downloaded the interpreter, the manuals come preinstalled. You can go online if necessary to www.python.org or you can view your manual to see the Fibonacci numbers that end in an "arbitrary" short, i.e. not the entire numerical value.

Seth

P.S. If you have any questions on where to find this section in your manual, please see The Python Tutorial/4. More Control Flow Tools/4.6 Defining Functions. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll check those sections of the manual.